# Bonecp getConnection hangs even though IdleMaxAgeInMinutes is set

Tags: java, database

I am using **bonecp** to handle connections to database.
Here is my test configuration.

```
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.104/" + DATABASE);
config.setUsername(USERNAME);
config.setPassword(PASSWD);
config.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(2);
config.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(4);
config.setIdleMaxAge(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
config.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
config.setConnectionTestStatement("SELECT 1");
config.setMaxConnectionAge(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
config.setPartitionCount(1);
```

I am trying to get connection from pool, after getting 4 connections from pool on getting **5th** connection getConnection **HANGS** as pool is **exhausted** as i am not closing the connections. But by configuration bonecp closes the connection after ageout which it is not happening.

What is the use of **IdleMaxAge, MaxConnectionAge and IdleConnectionTestPeriod** parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
config.setCloseOpenStatements(true);
```

I would also see why those statement stay open..